# Use Firestore to access images stored locally in a Flutter Project

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I have Images of flags stored locally within my Flutter project **assets/images** folder i stored name of the images in firestore by opening a collection called "Languages" then set fields two fields

Languages [Collection] with auto id documents
 1. Language_Image -> china.png [Fields]
 2. Language_Name -> Chinese [Fields]

I want to generate a GridView of the flags (CircleAvatar) of every language and name of the language (Text)
I don't know how to go about the process to iterate through each document and get Language_Image and Language_Name data and build my GridView here is my code
`

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'Choose_Books.dart';

class ChooseLanguage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text("Choose ChooseLanguage To Learn",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: ScreenUtil().setHeight(34)),
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
      ),
      body: ChooseLanguageBody(),
    );
  }
}

class ChooseLanguageBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChooseLanguageBodyState createState() => _ChooseLanguageBodyState();
}


class _ChooseLanguageBodyState extends State<ChooseLanguageBody> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Language').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
              child: const Text('Loading events...'));
        }return GridView.count(
          // Create a grid with 3 columns.
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: List.generate(24, (index) {
            return Center(
              child: CupertinoButton(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircleAvatar(
                      maxRadius: 70.0,
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/launguages/launguage${snapshot.data.documents[index]['Language_Image']}.png'),
                    ),
                      Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['Language_Image'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: ScreenUtil().setHeight(24), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                onPressed: () {Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChooseBook()));},
              ),
            );
          }),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

`
Is it the correct procedure am following or i messed up completely?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the Problem.
You missed adding the ***.data*** part.

Try this

```
snapshot.data.documents[index].data['Language_Image']
```

Hope this helps.!
(FYI-> your gig is lead to this problem)